# Button onclick doesn't work when URL has trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, button, slash

I have an asp Button control with a function tied to the Onclick Event.  I set up break points inside this function to see if the function gets called.

When I have the URL ending with "page.aspx", the button click event works properly.  When I have "page.aspx/", the click event doesn't seem to get called.

I read some other articles that talk about relative locations being changed due to the slash, but this problem doesn't seem to be about the same thing.

Does anyone know the problem?  Thank you.

Edit:

I have a button like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server" /
```

I have code like this:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView.SetActiveView(View0);
    }
```

Comment: Post aspx and cs code plz. Anything interesting in the web.config?

Comment: I added aspx button and the associated cs code.

Comment: Could you tell why do you need the trailing slash? Is it added automatically or you add it by yourself? I suppose that name of the page should end the address or can be followed with a query string if you need to pass some data there.

Comment: There is no real reason to add the trailing slash, but I was just testing the site.  I was surprised it wouldn't work just because of the trailing slash.  There isn't a query string being passed to the page.aspx.